# Why would US Senator Adam Schiff be addressed as "Chairmanship" rather than "Chairman"?

Tags: united-states, congress, terminology

At the very end of the December 11, 2022 Face The Nation video [Schiff says Jan. 6 committee's probe "far out ahead" of Justice Department](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=84PlmEfv-n0) the show's "moderator and CBS News senior foreign affairs correspondent Margaret Brennan" **thanks the Congressman and addresses him as "Charimanship" rather than "Chairman".**

As a member of the US Senate, [Adam Schiff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam_Schiff#Committee_assignments) is Chairman of the [United States House Permanent Select Committee on Intelligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_House_Permanent_Select_Committee_on_Intelligence)

**Question:** Why would US Senator Adam Schiff be addressed as "Chairmanship" rather than "Chairman"?

Comment: There is no political question here, as it is a simple mispronunciation. Upvote but close.

Comment: @JamesK *There certainly was* a political terminology question here, until the answer was posted and more information became available. I'd happily delete it but now it's got an answer so I can't. As it has now become a pile-on downvote magnet I'll happily close it.

Comment: I voted to re-open on principle because I agree with @uhoh. We can't expect people asking questions to know the answer to their question before they ask it. On it's face this is a valid, on-topic question with a benign simple answer. The only drawback I can see is potential "lack of research," but OP heard what they heard, and I had to listen to it twice since I was already biased to hear "chairmanship" after reading it first.

Comment: @JeffLambert well I'm sad because I've voted to close and even flagged the moderators for assistance to get it closed quickly. The primary function of closing a question is to prevent further answers, and since the current answer is accepted and complete and there's no possibility of meaningful future answers, it makes absolutely no sense in this particular case to reopen this. Would you please consider retracting your reopen vote? *Thanks!*

Comment: @uhoh For you? Sure thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Q: Why would US Senator Adam Schiff be addressed as "Chairmanship" rather than "Chairman"?

The moderator, Margaret Brennan, was misunderstood. The [transcript of the interview](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/adam-schiff-face-the-nation-transcript-12-11-2022/) shows "Chairman Schiff" in both places where she apparently said "chairmanship".

Comment: It did sound like "chairmanship" to my ear.

Comment: While I still can't hear the "ff", what I do hear is not incompatible with "Chairman Schiff". *Thanks!*